# In ESXi server, Why consumed host memory is more than allocated memory?

Tags: vmware-esxi, virtual-machines, vmware-vsphere, memory

I am using ESXi 4.0 and ESXi 4.1 for my VM needs.

I have allocated a VM with 4 GB RAM. Recently the user of that VM complained that he is unable to access the VM.

I was trying to connect it through remote desktop ( Remote settings were enabled in the Virtual machine.) ,but was not able to access it

Then i tried to connect it using Vsphere. Only a black screen was shown.

I verified summary page , it shows "Consumed host memory is 4165 MB". I had allocated just 4096 MB of RAM to it.

I am not able to understand how it is utilizing more than that and it is in unusable state now.I restarted the VM but still the problem persists after restarted.

What could be the reason for this? How to resume my machine's memory and make is usable again?

Comment: Virtualized guest has overhead? Naaawwww...

Answer (score 5):

There's two problems here, one is that your VM's crashed, just reboot it - the other is that you just need to know that consumed memory usually includes some amount of VM resource management memory too - hence why it's a little over the allocation, don't worry about it, the VM OS can't go over the 4096 you allocated.